# Compare 2 Text files line by line and replace when true or false

Tags: c#

I have 2 text (ini) files to compare. first one reads

```
NUMM=1
DURC=360
VORS=2500
SPAN=130
```

the second one reads

```
NUMM=0
DURC=340
VORS=3000
SPAN=140
```

in a third file I say which data form the first file should be replace in the second file by telling true or false

```
NUMM=false
DURC=true
VORS=true
SPAN=false
```

Result of the second file after replaceing should be

```
NUMM=1
DURC=340
VORS=3000
SPAN=130
```

I tried a few ways but could not work it out in C#

Comment: Perhaps you should describe a little bit about what you tried. I'm not sure I understand all of your description, but if I was to try and answer it, I'd basically be programming it myself. If you can show where you're getting messed up, people could try and address that.

Comment: Post what you tried.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: "I tried a few ways but could not work it out in C#" Why not? What went wrong? I know how to do this but maybe it's best if you write down what steps you should take and then implement it in C#.

Comment: Would you mind posting what you have tried so that we can point you in the right direction? Otherwise the only answer to this question would be a complete implementation of the above requirements...

Comment: Also, will (for example) `NUMM` exist more than once in each file? That you couldn't get it is not a bad thing, and we can help you figure it out, but help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do :

First, read and split the true/false file, to create a HashTable named htTrueFalse.

Then, read and split the first file, to create a HashTable named htReplace.

Finally, read and split the second file, and for each key, get from the htTrueFalse if I need to replace, and if I need to, get the value for the key from the htReplace, and replace it in the result file.

Mmmh ... Im'not sure this is particularly clear, if not, don't hesitate to ask for an example.

Comment: Exactly how I would do it, with the caveat you forgot to mention writing it back out again to the second file (since presumably that's the intent of this code) `Result of the second file after replaceing should be`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
var file1 = new StreamReader(filename1);
var file2 = new StreamReader(filename2);
var file3 = new StreamReader(filename3);
var output = string.Empty;
var line = string.Empty;

while((line = file1.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var replace = file3.ReadLine.Split('=')[1];
    if(replace == "true")
    {
        output += file2.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
        output += line + "\r\n";
    }
}

file1.Close;
file2.Close;
file3.Close;

var file4 = new StreamWriter(filename4);
file4.Write(output);
file4.Close;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would do:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<string> fileToWrite = new List<string>();
string[] file1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
string[] file2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(anotherFilePath);
string[] fileWithTrueFalse = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileWithTrueFalsePath);
for (int i = 0; i < file1.Length; i++)
{
    if (fileWithTrueFalse[i].Substring(fileWithTrueFalse[i].IndexOf('=') + 1) == "true")
        fileToWrite.Add(file2[i]);
    else
        fileToWrite.Add(file1[i]);
}
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(fileToWritePath, fileToWrite.ToArray());
```

Comment: Hello Cokegod your code nearly does what I want exept that the true false file has the defined true/false vales only ones but in the compare files the are repeated like

Comment: Hello Cokegod sorry didn't finish my comment. Your code nearly does what I want exept that the true false file has the defined true/false values only ones but in the compare files the are repeated like file1 NUMM=1 VORS=3000 DURC=360 NUMM=2 VORS=2500 DURC=340 and so on. file2 has NUMM=1 VORS=2500 DURC=350 NUMM=2 VORS=2400 DURC=330 and so on but the file3 (true false only has NUMM=false VORS=true DURC=false. If I run the code I get an Index error because I think in file1 and file to the NUMM, VORS, DURC are repeating but not in the file3 (true/false)

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ to get the final output and then write it to file.

```
public class TempList
{
    public TempList(string key1, string data1)
    {
        key = key1;
        data = data1;
    }
    public TempList()
    { }

    public string key;
    public string data;
}
{
    System.Collections.Generic.List<TempList> list1 = new System.Collections.Generic.List<TempList>();
        list1.Add(new TempList("NUMM", "1"));
        list1.Add(new TempList("DURC", "360"));
        list1.Add(new TempList("VORC", "2500"));

        System.Collections.Generic.List<TempList> list2 = new System.Collections.Generic.List<TempList>();
        list2.Add(new TempList("NUMM", "0"));
        list2.Add(new TempList("DURC", "340"));
        list2.Add(new TempList("VORC", "3000"));

        System.Collections.Generic.List<TempList> list3 = new System.Collections.Generic.List<TempList>();
        list3.Add(new TempList("NUMM", "false"));
        list3.Add(new TempList("DURC", "true"));
        list3.Add(new TempList("VORC", "false"));

        System.Collections.Generic.List<TempList> p = (from q in list1
                join w in list2 on q.key equals w.key
                join r in list3 on q.key equals r.key
                select new TempList
                {
                    key = q.key,
                    data = (r.data == "true") ? w.data : q.data
                }).ToList<TempList>();
    }
```

Use Textreader to populate the list1, list2 and list3 from CSV files and TextWriter to write the final ouput p to a file.

Comment: I use the code of cokegod and it works fine exept the true/fales value in this only exist ones. In the first and second file the value exist a few times. maybe it is easier in a program language:

Comment: I use the code of cokegod and it works fine exept the true/fales value in this only exist ones and so I get an index error.If I extend the true/false file by the same amount of lines like the first or compare file than it works exept I have to change true/false values in all lines (like the NUMM=true 84 times) . In the first and second file the value exist a few times like file_read NUMM=1....NUMM=2....NUMM=3 file compare NUMM=1....NUMM=3....NUMM=2 file true/false NUMM=true file result than NUMM=1....NUMM=2.....NUMM=3 same with other values. all values are line by line.